# Ordered dictionaries Python 3.6.5

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6, ordereddictionary

I am trying to preserve insertion order on a dictionary, I am using a for loop to insert elements. I tried using collections ordereddict but it does not seem to do the trick. How can I solve this ?
example:

```
import collections
a= ["ALT" , "TYPE", "EST"] 
attributes = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in a:
    attributes[i] = 1
```

I want the dictionary to be ordered alt, type, est but is ordere alt, est, type

Comment: *"does not seem to do the trick"* isn't a very helpful problem description, please give a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Done.

Comment: Could not reproduce, I get them in the expected order.

Comment: I was looking at the debug console and thought that was the order. Why does it have a different order in the debug console ?

Comment: What debug console? Maybe whatever you're using for that alphabetises the keys by default. What order do you see if you actually iterate over it, e.g. `list(attributes)`?

Comment: VSCode, yeah the order is correct, I was just wondering why the debug console alphabetizes it. Thanks.